# Relative clauses in X-Bar

Tags: parsing, x-bar-theory, relative-clauses

How do I break down the Complement further in accordance with X bar theory.

[image: COMPL]

Comment: I believe it's no longer fashionable to use more than one Bar (i.e, no N-Double Bar); a very long sentence makes for an uncomfortable number of Bars. I don't know what they do now, instead, though. Perhaps they're color-coded? In McCawley's version of x-bar, the `N-Double Bar` node is simply an `NP`, which is not, like N' (pronounced "N-Bar"; bars are hard to wordprocess, while primes are easy), a phrase headed by an N, but rather is a different type, outside the X-Bar system. `NP` is the syntactic constituent type corresponding to the logical type `Argument of Predicate`.

Comment: How do we break down the Complement though?

Comment: Any way you like. I'd say it was [_book_ [Adj [S ... S] Adj]], personally. (I wouldn't use X-bar at all; it adds nothing but complications and it's theoretically ill-defined.)

Comment: [book [Adj [S ... S] Adj]],  to be honest I don't know what that means. I was hoping someone could do a parse tree for me.

Comment: OK, you should not be studying X-bar theory until you get a firm idea of how trees work and why linguists use them for syntax. Try this [logic review](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf), which explains the bracket/parenthesis problem, and then this [Verb Phrase study guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf), which shows how parentheses expand into trees. No X-bar theory is needed or used.

Comment: I just want a basic tree diagram technique that lets me break down sentences into phrases. I agree that I will avoid X Bar. What you suggested I read looks a bit heavy for now but I will read it. But basically, "What I wrote" - is that an adjectival phrase? wrote is a verb so I don't understand how it can be a adjectival phrase.

Comment: _What I wrote_, (in, e.g: _What I wrote was pretty awful; He copied what I wrote_), is an embedded question [complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf) that's functioning as the subject or object of some predicate.  Since it can be subject or object, it's actually a noun phrase here, since nouns are the things that can be subjects or objects.

Comment: X-bar syntax is worth knowing only for its historical value in the development of syntactic theory. Serious syntacticians rejected X-bar structures decades ago.

Comment: @Jlawler, the clause "what I wrote" in your example is not an embedded question, but rather it is a free relative clause functioning as a subject or object argument. The predicates "awful" and "copy" do not take an interrogative argument.

Comment: @TimOsborne: There's no real difference in structure; either can be [disjunctive or conjunctive](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CQ-DQ-New.pdf). I'm happy with your terminology, too; I think the important thing is that both constructions function as noun phrases.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help with a specific tree diagram, now deemed to be off-topic.

Comment: @hippietrail: I prefer to leave this open because it's not about a specific sentence, but rather about how X-bar deals with relative clauses.

Comment: OK @prash I tried to read it to see which it was but this is not my field so obviously I got it wrong this time.

Answer (score 2):

I've given what i deem to be a reasonably standard phrase-structure tree for a *that*-relative clause, consistent with the principles of X-bar theory below (taking Jackendoff, 1977 as a concrete reference). I'm assuming the DP hypothesis here (i.e. that 'a book...' is headed by a determiner rather than by the noun), but it's easy to re-cast this in terms on an NP if that displeases you.

[image]

Relative clauses are generally taken in generative syntax to involve *wh*-movement. Since there is no overt *wh*-word in a *that*-relative, this is modelled by positing a null relative operator. Evidence that relative clauses involve *wh*-movement comes from facts like the following: (i) Relative clauses can be formed using *wh*-words, as in (1):

(1) A book which i bought.

(ii) Relativisation seems to obey the same constraints as *wh*-movement, e.g. It can cross a finite clause boundary, as indicated by (2):

(2) A book that Vera said Op_i that John had bought t_i.

(iii) Relativisation is blocked by the presence of a syntactic island. Sensitivity to islandhood is generally taken as being diagnostic of, or even definitional of *wh*-movement. This can be illustrated by the fact that (2) is ungrammatical, where movement out of a syntactic island - Specifically, a complex subject:

(3) *A book Op_i that a copy of t_i was stolen

Example (4) Shows that wh-movement out of a complex subject leads to ungrammaticality:

(4) *Which book was a copy of t_i stolen?

(iv) There are languages in which an overt realisation of a wh-word alongside *that* in a relative clause is grammatical, e.g. in Middle English:

(5) thy freend which that thou has lorn (cmctmeli.m3, 218.C1.31)
'your friend that you have lost' 
(Retrieved from: http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/ch11.html)

Comment: I would do the same. The only tiny thing that I think you have just forgot is to coindex book and operator.